# Synapse notebook storage csv as a folder format

Tags: python, azure, csv, azure-synapse

I am using Azure Synapse Notebook to store a spark dataframe as a csv file in the blob storage with the following code:

```
def pandas_to_spark(pandas_df):
    columns = list(pandas_df.columns)
    types = list(pandas_df.dtypes)
    struct_list = []
    for column, typo in zip(columns, types): 
      struct_list.append(define_structure(column, typo))
    p_schema = StructType(struct_list)
    return sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_df, p_schema)

def define_structure(string, format_type):
    try: typo = equivalent_type(format_type)
    except: typo = StringType()
    return StructField(string, typo)


csvString = str(r_csv.content.decode('latin-1'))
csvString = csvString.replace('Metadata Internal','')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csvString), sep= ',')
df_2 = df[['Metadata ID','Metadata Title']]
sparkdf = pandas_to_spark(df_2)
sparkdf.show()
csv_report_path = wasbs_path + 'UUID_List.csv' 
sparkdf.write.csv(csv_report_path, mode = 'overwrite', header = 'true')
```

The output of the code gives me a csv folder and inside the folder is csv files. The problem is if I want to download the csv, I can only download them pieces by pieces.

How can I store the csv file without them break in parts?

[out put of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjz0e.png)
[Inside folder, there are csv pieces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0SDH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collapse the output to a single file in pyspark using *coalesce(1)*
NOTE: example targets ADLS instead of Blob Storage, but the principle should be the same.

```
# Output using Spark
output_container_path = "abfss://{your_container_name}@{your_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net"
full_output_name = "{}/{}/{}".format(output_container_path,output_folder_name,output_blob_name)

(queryData
 .coalesce(1)
 .write
 .mode("overwrite")
 .option("header", "true")
 .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
 .save(full_output_name))
```

The downside is you will get 1 file, but you can't control the name, so it will have a very unhelpful name like *QID1599336_20210414_184911_0.txt*.