# Azure Synapse SQL results (pyspark) to store as CSV

Tags: pyspark

This may be an uncommon question and I could not find a clear help, but is it possible to export a PySper SQL Query results as CSV straight to an Azure Data Lake Storage?

To add some context, I have a synapse and I use PySpark with SQL statement. I want to save results of my query as the csv file. At the moment, Pyspark save results however splits into multiple Part files.

part-0000....

I have tired multiple ways but all of them give me the same result

```
df.write.format("csv").option("header", "true").save("abfss://raw@.....dfs.core.windows.net/Reporting/11.csv")
df.write.format("csv").option('header','true').save("abfss://raw@....dfs.core.windows.net/Reporting/xyzz.csv")
```

Also, the csv file name is used to create a folder in Azure Lake Storage and not a file name.

Comment: Does this answer your question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67728073/synapse-notebook-storage-csv-as-a-folder-format)

Comment: Not really. First I would need to control the csv filename and also that code does not save df as csv in my lake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that

```
df = df.repartition(1)
```

does the trick. The only this is that the file name is not controlled.